# Close a resource in a Finally block from a try catch with resources

Tags: java, try-catch-finally

I have in my code the next:

```java
try (DockerClient client = DefaultDockerClient.fromEnv().connectTimeoutMillis(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3)).build()) {
    //some code here
}catch (DockerCertificateException e) {
    log.warn("Failed to connect Docker Client {}", e.getMessage());
}
finally {

}
```

I need to close the client in the final block, but I can't because I'm getting an error (Cannot resolve symbol client).

Is there any way to close this client in the final block?

Comment: Why do you need to close it in the `finally` block if you're using try with resources?

Comment: Because inside the code could be some exceptions, I'm using the client inside the main try, but I need to close the connection at the end of whole process.

Comment: @YuCheng Please post that as an answer and delete the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client will be closed, cause you are using try-with-resources (when you open resourse in `try(resource definition)`), which closes resource after try block automatically, you don`t need to write finally block.

Answer (score 1):

The object in try(...) must implement `AutoClosable` and that object will be automatically closed whether or not an exception happens. You don't need the finally block at all.

If the object does not implement `AutoClosable`, you can fall back to the old try-catch-finally block as

```
DockerClient client = null;
try {
  //some code here
  client = DefaultDockerClient.fromEnv().connectTimeoutMillis(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3)).build();
} catch (DockerCertificateException e) {
  log.warn("Failed to connect Docker Client {}", e.getMessage());
} finally {
  if (client != null) client.close();        
}
```

This is called the Java try-with-resources block. You can see an example that compares normal try-catch-finally block with the try-with-resources block here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources#replacing

Comment: The object is from a library, do you mean I have to create a wrapper which inherit from DockerClient and implement closeable? or something similar?

Comment: You can do that, but I suggest you simply use the old try-catch-finally block as shown in my edited answer.